# The double 'i' is cool, but what's the rule?

Tags: grammatical-number, suffixes

At least to a self-professed geek, it's cool to write words like *fungii* and *radii*, so naturally, in some informal communications, I take every opportunity to apply the suffix where it's probably not supposed to be used.

Thus I ask, what is (are) the rule(s) for the double 'i'?

Comment: The rule is replace "us" with "i". *fungus→fungi*; *radius→radii*, *Prius→Prii* (although the last one is technically invalid, since it only works with Latin words of the second declension).

Comment: It isn't there in _fungi_; that's a single I. In _radii_, the first I is part of the root _radi-_ and the second I is the plural nominative suffix _-i_. The best rule for using Latin plurals in English is to **get them right**. If you have to ask about the rules, you should study Latin.

Comment: @MDMoore313: As should be obvious by now, there are risks involved if you latch on to "cool" usages without knowing what's right, and why. You surely don't want people to remember you for decades to come as the guy who once told them **fungii** was a cool word (but some time later they discovered it wasn't even a valid word at all). Me, I think you should go with the future (which means getting used to regular forms such as **corpuses** rather than stuffy old-fashioned **corpora**).

Comment: And note that it's *corpora* and not *corpi* because *corpus* is a Latin word in the **third declension**.

Comment: @WS2: As should be obvious from my previous comment, I'd unquestionably go for **referendums**. Interestingly, people still think Brits are linguistically "conservative" (simply because we never had anything like Webster's revisions), but the evidence from corpuses suggests we're actually *leading* the move towards regularising things like **dialog**, **funguses**, etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Getting it wrong before your peers is seldom forgiven. When I was at school, well over half a century ago, we were, one day, taking it in turns to read aloud in class. One boy pronounced the word 'wholly' as if it were spelled 'wally'. We were no more than 11 years old and were always known to our peers and the teachers by our surnames. But all through grammar school thereafter, this chap, whose Christian name I think was David, was always known as 'Wally'. I sometimes wonder if he is still around as he approaches 70 and if his wife calls him Wally without knowing why!

Comment: @WS2: That was my exact point! Not only can schoolboys be merciless *at the time* - the worst of it is we all tend to remember a few "howlers" from way back when.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ‘i’ is a Latin plural. ‘Fungus’ is the singular and ‘fungi’ (**not** 'fungii’) is the plural. The letter ‘i’ occurs twice at the end of ‘radii’ only because there’s an ‘i’ in the singular ‘radius’.